# Mockito mocking AhcWSClient

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

I'm trying to mock a Rest Client(`AhcWSClient`) in my Spec using Mockito. However, it is just returning a `Null Pointer Exception`. This is what I have:

```
import org.specs2.matcher.Scope
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito

class MyRestClientSpec(implicit ev: ExecutionEnv) extends Specification with Mockito {

trait Context extends Scope with MyRestClient {
  val mockWsClient: WSClient = mock[AhcWSClient]
  val mockWsResponse: WSResponse = mock[WSResponse]
  override def wsClient = mockWsClient
}

"findResponse" should {
  "give me my response" in new Context {
    val response = "Hello"
    when(mockWsResponse.body).thenReturn(response)
    when(wsClient.url("Dummyurl.com").get).thenReturn(Future(mockWsResponse)) //***
    val result = findResult("request")
  }
}
```

and then:

```
trait MyRestClient {
  def wsClient: WSClient = AhcWSClient()
}
```

The NPE is thrown on the line marked with *** and happens when `wsClient.url("Dummyurl.com")` is called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe a URL must have a scheme, like "http://" or something like that? BTW, why do you mock `WSResponse`? I think `mockWsClient` should be enough.

Comment: What is the full signature of `wsClient.url`? Are there some implicit parameters?